# How can I include one language file in another on a separate CI installation?

Tags: codeigniter

I have two CI installations

> /aCI/
>   /aCI/bCI/

How can I include lang file from bCI in aCI xxx_lang.php? I tried to add this:

```
include('../../../../bCI/application/language/english/xxx_lang.php');
```

...in `xxx_lang.php` in `aCI/application/language/xxx_lang.php` but it does not work.

I want to do this because it saves time; when I change something in "bCI" languages and I can use it in "aCI" site.

Comment: try write your full path like '/var/www/domain..etc'

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you mean the path is wrong? What error do you get?

Comment: "does not work" - requested lang file is not included into original lang file. so variables don't exist.

Comment: SAFAROV, thanks, you're right. it solved my problem include(FCPATH.'bCI/application/language/english/xxx_lang.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try write your full path like '/var/www/domain..etc'

I strongly recommend you to read this artile [Codeigniter Multiple_Applications](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications/).
Not only language, you can also share library, models, helpers and etc.

Comment: SAFAROV, thanks, you're right. this solved my problem include(FCPATH.'bCI/application/language/english/xxx_lang.php'); CI for multiple apps looks better I will use Codeigniter Multiple_Applications in my next app.